# Functional Programming-Style Map Function that adds elements?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I know and love my `filter`, `map` and `reduce`, which happen to be part of more and more languages that are not really purely functional.

I found myself needing a similar function though: something like `map`, but instead of one to one it would be one to many.

I.e. one element of the original list might be mapped to multiple elements in the target list.

Is there already something like this out there or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: I don't know about Haskell, but wouldn't that be equivalent to `map` returning an array of objects then `reduce` to join them together?

Comment: Incidentally, since you mention `filter` and `map`, note that both of those can be implemented in terms of the "one to many" operation you describe (which, as shown in the comments, is `concatMap`, or `>>=`). You may enjoy the exercise of implementing `filter` and `map` in terms of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) specialized to lists does.

```
> [1..6] >>= \x -> take (x `mod` 3) [1..]
[1,1,2,1,1,2]
```

It's [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat)enating together the results of

```
> map (\x -> take (x `mod` 3) [1..]) [1..6]
[[1],[1,2],[],[1],[1,2],[]]
```

Comment: You can use `concatMap` if you don’t like strange symbols.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, but then you're missing out on the connection to tree grafting and all that other monadic goodness.

Comment: Sure, but I find it more natural to first point to `concatMap`, and then, as a remark to those who can make use of it, point out that `(>>=)=concatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to roll your own.  There are many relevant functions here, but I'll highlight three.

First of all, there is the [`concat` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat), which already comes in the Prelude (the standard library that's loaded by default).  What this function does, when applied to a list of lists, is return the list that contains concatenated contents of the sublists.

**EXERCISE:** Write your own version of `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`.

So using `concat` together with `map`, you could write this function:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f = concat . map f
```

...except that you don't actually need to write it, because it's such a common pattern that [the Prelude already has it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) (at a more general type than what I show here—the library version takes any `Foldable`, not just lists).

Finally, there is also the `Monad` instance for list, which can be defined this way:

```
instance Monad [] where
  return a = [a]
  as >>= f = concatMap f as
```

So the `>>=` operator (the centerpiece of the `Monad` class), when working with lists, is exactly the same thing as `concatMap`.

**EXERCISE:** Skim through the documentation of the [`Data.List` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html).  Figure out how to import the module into your code and play around with some of the functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and exercises – I like it!